# Url rewrite on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some problems with my URL rewriting.

I just want to change my URL paradigm's who is :
http://www.siteadress.com/index.php?//something/something to something like that :
http://www.siteadress.com/something/something

So I add this line :
RewriteRule (.*?)index.php\?/*(.*) /$1$2
But that does'nt work as I planned. 
That just remove 1 / from my URL.

Yet in my meaning, I ask for (.*?) anything optionnal  index.php\?/* index.php?// (.*) and anything, no?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the rule in reverse order. The first argument should be the pattern you're looking to match, the second argument being what you want to replace it to. In your case, you're looking for "/something/something" and wanting to rewrite that to "/index.php?//something/something". So you need something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /index.php?//$1
```

That will take anything after the first / in the path and append it to /index.php?//.

Comment: Thank you for your replay.

I just thnik I misunderstood myself, I don't want to append something to the /index.php?//, I want to 'delete it' to have 'good looking URLs'.

I tested what you have sent and for me it's as you say that append to the /index.php?//
But if I delete all my URL rewriting, I have already the url like : http://somthing/index.php?//something

That's why I want to add a rule to delete this.
Thank you.